# Android ChatHead is limiting the touch to itself only, BUT I need support second finger simultaenously second touching the area outside the chathead,

Tags: android

http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/
By following this good guide, I can make a chathead and also detect the touch event.
However, if I touch the chathead with first finger, and try to touch other area (outside) the chathead with second finger, the second touch is not possible.
(The area outside can be the home screen, or another app, activity)
Similarly, IF I first touch the outside, and try to use second finger to touch the chathead, it is not possible.
I tried the similar interaction with facebook messenger chathead and it is the same.

My question is: is it possible to support the second touch?
maybe using dispatch touch event? but afaik dispatch is only for activity.
the chathead uses service and window.

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: the code is inside the link I posted, basically I just use the same code.  
http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

Comment: that's a guide... that's not your code. BTW... why an user would like to touch the chathead and other thing at the same time? That's a really bad UX.

Comment: I am using exactly the same code posted in the link.  I am not concerned about good or bad UX becauseI am not developing consumer application. It is for special purpose interaction. Please post solution instead of meaningless comment.

Comment: This isn't possible using `WindowManager` added layouts. Once you start a touch event on a view, all subsequent touch events will be sent to the same listener until ALL `MotionEvent`s are finished (I.e `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_CANCEL` has occurred).

Comment: I've added clarification to my answer explaining why it's not possible in this circumstance. I'd appreciate the answer being accepted, as it is correct, despite it not being the answer you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible using the following workaround.

- Have a transparent layout surrounding your chathead.
- This
  transparent layout will intercept the touch and you can do the necessary
  handling.
- You can then pass this touch event up the hierarchy/other apps by returning false from `OnTouchEvent()`.

To let the other apps handle touch event,the transparent view can only be activated when the user is already touching your chathead.This way you cna make sure that the user is planning to do some gesture with your chathead.

Comment: can you provide proof-of-concept sample? Like how to pass touch event up the hierarchy? Because my chathead is on top of other applications (not my own activity)

Comment: Not possible in this situation as the views outside the chathead are not in the same hierarchy.

Comment: @KaneO'Riley ...I meant passing the event to the system/other apps.

Comment: Return false in `onTouchEvent` does NOT pass the event to another view heirarchy.

Comment: Your answer is still wrong. At best, a second simultaneous touch will perform the same way it is now, without the superfluous transparent layout. Nothing will get passed to another view hierarchy once the first touch event is initiated.

Comment: @KaneO'Riley that is what the issue is - "touch the chathead with first finger, and try to touch other area (outside) the chathead with second finger, the second touch is not possible"

Comment: Yes, he wants the second touch to get passed to the underlying activity, not capture it for the chathead which is what your suggestion will do (and is what is already happening due to how system overlay windows work).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible using layouts manually added to the `WindowManager` as a system overlay when the underlying view is from a completely different hierarchy.

Once you start a touch event on the first view, all subsequent touch events will be sent to the same view heirarchy until ALL `MotionEvent`s are finished (I.e `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_CANCEL` has occurred).

Basically, once you are interacting with one view heirarchy, any outside touches are interpreted as touches outside the current heirarchy, and ignore any underlying view heirarchies which may or may not occupy the same screen position.

Comment: is it possible to check for the touch outsides positions? and the send to the activity below using some kind of dispatch touch event or injecting touch event? I have root and using aosp like rom (CM12.1 to be exact), so permission is not a problem.

Comment: It's not possible to find out what the view below the touch is in this situation, much less dispatch the touch to it I'm afraid.